# What could be wrong when mkdir, file and touch command give error messages

Tags: linux, command-line, security, hardware, troubleshooting

At certain time, various commands started to give various error messages.

I catched a few of them and then rebooted the system and these commands were working.

```
$ mkdir x
  mkdir: cannot create directory `x':
$ file x.txt
  bash: /usr/bin/file:
    Input/output error
$ touch x.txt
  Segmentation fault
```

There were other commands giving the same error messages.
ls, px was working.
Some command output "read/only filesystem".

Now it's OK after reboot.

What could I try (to measure or diagnose) to know more about what was happening? If it's rather relating to hardware or security?

Comment: hardware. Most likely a bad drive or faulty cable.

Comment: Could have been the filesystem got mounted read-only.

Comment: @DopeGhoti It might, but that would have been a consequence of the same I/O problem, not a cause of these messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next step would probably involve looking at your `dmesg | tail -40` output. Then again, it would probably answer with an other Input/output error. I guess you had to physically reboot this machine/commands were failing as well?

Looks like your root filesystem is gone.
Could be a problem with a disk, some sata cable, or a faulty RAID array.

Comment: Yes, I had to physically reboot. So, you eliminate security risk? Or I can focus on something to be more sure?

Comment: By focus, I mean, use the command with grep, to get more precise information related to the situation before reboot.

Comment: From my experiences, these kind of messages are related to some hardware issue. You could try configuring rsyslog to forward messages to some remote logger: missing disks/broken root doesn't mean your running processes are necessarily broken too.

Comment: If `file` input/output errors, my bet is `grep` won't work any better.

Comment: dmesg shouldn't fail with an input/output error because dmesg info is stored in memory, not on disk.

Comment: Dmesg isn't a shell built-in. If the binary's not available, I wouldn't expect it to work. Worth trying, which was the point of my initial post.

Comment: It started with youtube, not working, then internet not working.
Now, youtube is starting not working.

Comment: grep is working now. Can I filter the output of dmesg? You are inclined to hardware issues, this is too broad for me to accept it as an answer now.

Comment: I don't use RAID array, so you say a disk or sata cable? Why do you think so? There is segmentation fault as well, which usually refers to RAM.

Comment: I'm not sure trying to use grep with dmesg would be of any help, not knowing what you're looking for. If you can run commands, then run `dmesg`. Eventually, `dmesg | tail -40` or similar. I couldn't explain why commands could segfault though, this is a good remark.

Comment: OK, I will close the question. Please append to your answer `dmesg | tail -40` with a bold face.

Comment: I noticed `$ ps aux | grep scsi
root        37  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec16   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root        38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec16   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root      5879  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec19   0:00 [scsi_eh_4]
root      6443  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec19   0:00 [scsi_eh_6]
root      6595  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec19   0:00 [scsi_eh_7]`

Comment: According to [this page](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/scsi_eh_%5B0-7%5D-processes-578746/) it could relate to SCSI error handler.